# Changing the img src through javascript whilst src is stored in an array

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to change the source of an image on page load yet instead of the image itself loading, the string of it's location is being displayed. Most likely a simple solution but i cannot see it.

```
<form id="form1"><h1 id="dude">question?</h1><br>
                    <h2>
                        <label for ="answer1" id="label1"><img src="imgs//img.png" id="img1" width="150" height = "150"></label>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer1">
                    </h2><br>
                    <h2>
                        <label for ="answer2" id="label2"><img src="imgs//img.png" id="img2" width="150" height = "150"></label>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer2">
                    </h2><br>
                    <h2>
                        <label for="answer3" id="label3"><img src="imgs//img.png" id="img3" width="150" height = "150"></label>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer3">
                    </h2>
                    <h2>
                        <label for="answer4" id="label4"><img src="imgs//img.png" id="img4" width="150" height = "150"></label>
                        <input type="radio" name"answer" id="answer4">
                    </h2>
                </form>
```

and the javascript

```
//  populate mulChoiImg array   
mulChoiImg[1] = new Array('Which picture do you like most', 'imgs//img2.png','imgs//img2.png','imgs//img2.png','imgs//img2.png');
function popMulC(){
                document.getElementById("dude").innerHTML= mulchoi[currentQuestion][0];
                document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML=mulchoi[currentQuestion][1];
                document.getElementById("label2").innerHTML=mulchoi[currentQuestion][2];
                document.getElementById("label3").innerHTML=mulchoi[currentQuestion][3];
                document.getElementById("label4").innerHTML=mulchoi[currentQuestion][3];}//close func
```

any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're using double slashes `imgs//` remove one.

Comment: There is still no change?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually changing your image src, but rather just the innerHtml of the Label element.

You need to get your image element from the label and then do `image.src = mulchoi[currentQuestion][1];`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
 var mulChoiImg = new Array('Which picture do you like most', 'imgs/img2.png','imgs/img2.png','imgs//img2.png','imgs/img2.png');

function popMulC(){
 document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = "<img src=" + mulChoiImg[1] + "/>";
 }
```